# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am facing a strange error! I am trying to dynamically render products on my UI. When I have in my code:

```
 render () {
    const cart = this.props.cart
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Products List</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>#</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Code Item</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  {cart.length > 0 && 
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                      <td>{cart[0].title}</td>
                      <td>{cart[0].code}</td>
                      <td>{cart[0].quantity}</td>
                      <td>{cart[0].price}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>}
                </table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

It renders the first item, however if I try to choose the 3rd item: i.e. {cart[2].title} and so on gives my the error that "title" is not defined. Plus if i try to give [i] gives me an error that "i" is not defined! Any ideas how to solve it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is `this.props.cart`? please update your question

Comment: @ Ali Yaghoby "const cart = this.props.cart" It is declared there cause I am using redux and further down the code I have: const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tbody goes outside the loop,then you need to add a key to each item.

```
<tbody>
{cart.length > 0 && cart.map((item, index) => (             
   <tr key={item.id}>
     <th scope="row">{index}</th>
     <td>{item.title}</td>
     <td>{item.code}</td>
     <td>{item.quantity}</td>
     <td>{item.price}</td>
  tr>))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render all your items in the cart array, then go with:

```
              {cart.map(c =>  
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>{c.title}</td>
                  <td>{c.code}</td>
                  <td>{c.quantity}</td>
                  <td>{c.price}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>}
```